# Wipe out value from table

Tags: postgresql

```
IntegrityError: insert or update on table "procurement_order" violates foreign key constraint "procurement_order_sale_line_id_fkey"
DETAIL:  Key (sale_line_id)=(71) is not present in table "sale_order_line".
```

I have this error and I know that if I will wipe the value in procurement_order table then the problem will be solved.

So the question is how can I do this using PostgreSQL because I'm not really used it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No problem, just make sure you back up the database first, in case something goes wrong.

The following command will wipe all data from table procurement_order:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE procurement_order;
```

If this gives you an error, it means that wiping the table violates one or more foreign key constraints. In this case, run the following command -- but understand that it will also wipe the contents of referencing tables:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE procurement_order CASCADE;
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Post the data from both procurement_order and sale_order_line,  you are probably just using  the wrong value for a foreign key

Comment: i can't access data, i just need a command that will  wipe out data from that table